# Log4net log file not created when unity app installed and running in another system

Tags: unity-game-engine, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have added log4net log file to my unity app. When I run my app in my own machine log files created successfully and log the data but when I publish build of my app and run it in another system, log files are not created. Please suggest any idea what I am missing while created in log file. Here is the code used for create log file.

### Sample code :

```
  public static void ConfigureAllLogging()
    {
        try
        {
            var patternLayout = new PatternLayout
            {
                ConversionPattern = "%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline"
            };
            patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

            // setup the appender that writes to Log\EventLog.txt
            var fileAppender = new RollingFileAppender
            {
                AppendToFile = true,
                File = @"TestLog/log.txt",
                Layout = patternLayout,
                MaxSizeRollBackups = 1,
                MaximumFileSize = "10MB",
                RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size,
                StaticLogFileName = true,
                LockingModel = new RollingFileAppender.MinimalLock(),


            };


            fileAppender.ActivateOptions();

            var unityLogger = new UnityAppender
            {
                Layout = new PatternLayout()
            };
            unityLogger.ActivateOptions();

            BasicConfigurator.Configure(fileAppender);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            LoggingManager.Error(ex, "ConfigureAllLogging", "Log4netLogHelper");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the TestLog directory exist?

Comment: No, when application started log file is created in that path.

Comment: Well, since your problem is the log file is not created, it seems like you might want to create that directory. Where is the program installed? Do you have permission to write to the directory where the log file would be created?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add any permissions to create directory because when I run in my own system it's work well that's why I have think that no need to add any permissions to create directory. Please give an idea how to create directory in program installed location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very likely that the issue is due to where you're saving the file. The code will work in the Editor but fail in a build. Unity expects you to save and read data from [`Application.persistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html). This is the only path you can read and write to in Unity across every platform.

Replace

```
File = @"TestLog/log.txt",
```

with

```
File = Application.persistentDataPath + "/TestLog/log.txt";
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try above code and update the result.